# set year in react-datetime. function onChange

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker

my YearPicker works but it also give me an error and after 24h battle i give up. I don't know what is going on. Please help :)

there's is react code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Datetime from "react-datetime";
import 'react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css';

export const DatePickerComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () =>{
    const [year, setYear] = useState('')

    useEffect( () => {

    })
    return (
        <>
            <h3>Wybierz rok</h3>
            <Datetime dateFormat="YYYY" timeFormat={false} onChange={(date) => setYear(date.year())}/>
            <h5>You selected year: {year}</h5>
        </>
    );
}
```

[and there is an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW3bC.png)

Answer (score 0):

`react-datetime` returns a moment date.

`import moment from 'moment'` then use it like this:

`onChange={(date)=>console.log(moment(date).year())}`